# Facebook IOS SDK: Detect when user reject the publish_stream permission

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I have an app that is using the facebook connect to get the basic user infos and post on the user news feed.

Basically i'm using this code to get the permissions

```
   if ( ! [facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"user_about_me", 
                                @"email",
                                @"publish_stream",
                                nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
    }
```

It's working great but if the user doesn't allow the "Extended permissions" (publish_stream) i would like to avoid asking the user if he would like to post on his news feed.

So is there any way to know if the user doesn't allow the publish_stream permission via the FB SDK ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, i post it since it could be useful for someone.

So the best way i found to know if the user allow the application to post on his news feed is to load his permissions through a graph request and parse the result.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" andDelegate:self];
```